# incremented value of loop variable fails to produce 1-6 count

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration, increment

So I'm trying to make two things happen at once. First is to run my loop six times, each time adding a new value to my array which will be the value of i during that iteration. The end result should be: arrayname [0,1,2,3,4,5]. My code (simplified) follows -

```
  var arrayname = new Array();

  for (var i=0;i<6;i++){

  arrayname[i] = i.value;

  }
```

For some reason I keep returning :

arrayname [undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]

I suspect a scope issue but when I type i into the console it returns 6!
So my loop is incrementing, but my array is is populated by undefined values!!

Please help!

Comment: You just created `i`, so why would it have a value property ?

Comment: Why are you using `i.value`? You typed just `i` into the console.

Comment: As a sidenote, looks like you're looking for `var arrayname = new Array(6);`, or if for some strange reason you need an array with 6 numbers, `arrayname.push(i)`

Comment: No this is simplified. The six comes from another function, I just didn't want to over-complicate this because that has nothing to do with this particular problem. I want to use i as a value because I'm adding id="1" id="2" etc etc to an unknowable number of containers, so as my loop iterates I want to end up with a total count and a 1,2,3,4 upward count of values (from the same logical process)

Comment: I think I thought i would have a value is because it is being used as an index and the index's value. It didn't occur to me that I was accessing i as a variable and not through arrayname! Oops :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is a primitive - it doesn't have a value property - just access it's value directly:

```
arrayname[i] = i;
```

Comment: You are dead on! I don't understand why var i = 0 in the for loop doesn't create act like a value in an array but I guess its because the value of the variable hasn't been accessed from the array but from the variable name itself separate from the array entirely or something. Anyway, spot on, thank you very much!